# THREE.js - Cloned and rotated LOD objects - wrong shading

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting, shading, level-of-detail

I have a txt. file exported from 3ds Max with name of objects, position, rotation and scale. 
Secondly I have a javascript initial list of this objects with paths on extern obj. and mtl. files.
From initial list I create a LOD objects that are cloned across my scene according to txt file. 
But I have a problem with shading/lighting of these cloned object that are rotated in the scene.

Please do you know what needs updating after I place the objects in scene?

[Two clones of same LOD object with different shading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FYC4.jpg)

[Here is a link on my project](http://storgine.cz/3d/10.php)

Piece of txt files with positioning of objects (name-of-LOD+number;positionXYZ;rotation;scale):

```
tree_small013;17.5686;0.15;34.1358;-0.0001;180.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
tree_small014;17.5686;0.15;44.5792;-0.0001;180.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
tree_small015;17.5686;0.15;13.1515;-0.0001;180.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
tree_small016;17.5686;0.15;65.6183;-0.0001;180.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
tree_small017;17.5686;0.15;55.1539;-0.0001;180.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement_corner;20.0;0.0;73.5;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement;20.0;0.0;70.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement_tree;20.0;0.0;63.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement001;20.0;0.0;66.5;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement_tree001;20.0;0.0;52.5;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement002;20.0;0.0;56.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement003;20.0;0.0;59.5;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
pavement004;20.0;0.0;34.9999;0.0;0.0;0.0;1.0;1.0;1.0
```

Example of importList.js with initializing LOD objects:

```
// STATIC MODELS IMPORT LIST
var models = {
    tree_small: {
    levels: {
            0: {
                name:"high",
                obj:"models/tree_small_high.obj",
                mtl:"maps/mtl/tree_small_high.mtl",
                mesh:null,
                dist:10
            },
            1: {
                name:"mid",
                obj:"models/tree_small_mid.obj",
                mtl:"maps/mtl/tree_small_mid.mtl",
                mesh:null,
                dist:15
            },
            2: {
                name:"low",
                obj:"models/tree_small_low.obj",
                mtl:"maps/mtl/tree_small_low.mtl",
                mesh:null,
                dist:20
            }               
        },  
        lod: null,
        shadows: true
    },
    pavement_corner: {
    levels: {
            0: {
                name:"high",
                obj:"models/pavement_corner_high.obj",
                mtl:"maps/mtl/pavement_corner_high.mtl",
                mesh:null,
                dist:10
            }                   
        },  
        lod: null,
        shadows: true
    },
    pavement: {
    levels: {
            0: {
                name:"high",
                obj:"models/pavement_high.obj",
                mtl:"maps/mtl/pavement_high.mtl",
                mesh:null,
                dist:10
            }                   
        },  
        lod: null,
        shadows: false
    },
```

Function Obj() in models.js which take a clone of LOD object and set it in scene by a txt. file:

```
function Obj(objName, x,y,z, rx,ry,rz, sx,sy,sz, mass, friction, flag){

    var offset = 0;
    var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    var quat = new THREE.Quaternion();

    this.obj = models[objName].lod.clone(false);
    this.obj.layers.set(objName);
    this.obj.name = objName;
    this.obj.position.set(x,y,z);
    this.obj.rotation.set(rx,ry,rz);
    this.obj.scale.set(sx,sy,sz);

    this.obj.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
    this.obj.matrixAutoUpdate = true;
    this.obj.updateMatrixWorld();
    this.obj.children[0].geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;

    makeObj(this.obj, 0); // add to collision system 

    this.obj.levels[0].object.updateMatrix();
    this.obj.children[0].updateMatrix();

    this.obj.levels[0].object.updateMatrixWorld();
    this.obj.children[0].updateMatrixWorld();

    this.obj.levels[0].object.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    this.obj.levels[0].object.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    this.obj.children[0].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    this.obj.children[0].geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    this.obj.updateMatrix();
    this.obj.updateMatrixWorld();

    scene.add(this.obj);

    return this.obj;        
}
```

Comment: Does the bug happen *only* when you rotate them? Or does the position also affect their color?

Comment: Only rotation. The same problem is on tops of houses models - facade is back to the sun but top cornice is lightened from below. Correct lighting is only on clones they have default rotation from 3ds Max.I thought that was wrong normal map, but if I turn off normal maps its same.

Comment: Have you tried using https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper to see where the normals are pointing? At first glance, it sounds like your vertices are being rotated, but the normals aren't responding nicely to the rotation.

Comment: Now I tried VertexNormalsHelper and all normals seems good.  https://imgur.com/a/pnGRpr7